# jQuery to pull op a TD element from the table and show it on an empty box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a project to create the Periodic table of elements, it has been done many times before but mine is learning purpose.

As seen from the pic I want to when I mouse over the element, the category should be filled up with that element but this time "zoomed in".

I pull the data is from `mysql` database via `mysqli`

Here is a row and right below a picture to have a clearer idea:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $numResultsgr1r2e1; $i++){
        $row1col1_2e1_2 = $resultgr1r2e1->fetch_object();
?>
    <td id="<?php echo $string = str_replace(' ','',$row1col1_2e1_2->cat_name); ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Helium" >
        <p class="emer-mase-atomik"><?php echo $row1col1_2e1_2->atomic_number ?></p>
        <p class="simbol"><?php echo $row1col1_2e1_2->symbol ?></p>
        <p class="emer-mase-atomik" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $row1col1_2e1_2->name ?>"><?php echo $row1col1_2e1_2->name ?><br><?php echo round($row1col1_2e1_2->molar_mass, 3); ?></p>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You could copy the content of the `td` and place it into your box:
`$('div#myBox').html(clickedElement.html())` - Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sjm710nx/

Comment: I suggest that you run the sql query (once at page load) to get all the elements and associated details and output that as a javascript object / json object and use a simple javascript event handler to look up the relevant information in the data object so you can display it in whatever manner you wish.

Comment: i want to create something similar to this: http://anthony-o.com/Ptable/